# Spring @Scheduled(cron = "0 * * * * ?") not run every hour

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cron

Using Spring Boot 1.5.4. `@Scheduled(cron = "0 * * * * ?")` should run task every minute. In one of my system it run every minute perfectly, but in another system(CentOS 6.3) it is not run every hour, i.e., it run at 14:58, run at 14:59, not run at 15:00, and then run at 15:01. What will cause this problem? how can I debug and find out the reason that it is not running at I expect?

Comment: You should test it at https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html

Comment: For every minute I think it should be */1 * * * * ?

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi the first digit is second,and the 2nd digit is minute,  according to Spring doc. Are you suggesting ` * */1 * * * ?`

Comment: Ok in that case yes it should be  * */1 * * * ?

Comment: cronmaker(http://www.cronmaker.com/) suggest the cron expression fro every minute is 0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *

Answer (score 0):

It's just a hypothesis, but assuming that the Cron expression is correct (otherwise just check it again) and behaves differently on different machines the following can be a possible reason:

`@Scheduled` by default works in a way that it opens `java.util.Timer` which is single-threaded.

So if the code of the method that gets executed runs more than one minute, the subsequent invocation will be delayed (won't happen), only because the thread is already "occupied".

So to check yourself, try to do the following:

Define `@Scheduled` method so that it will run every minute but will just print some message to log (so that it will for sure take less than one minute). 
If you see that it now behaves correctly, then it was indeed a problem, if not - it should be elsewhere.